# I don´t know how to add a search function within this app in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, full-text-search

I am coding a small app in React as part of a bootcamp assignment. The app should be able to do the following:

-An app with a list of workers, to be displayed: OK

-To be able to add more workers (email and name) and have them added to the list: OK

-Clear the form after submission: OK

-Use encapsulated components for the different functions: OK

-Use some boostrap: OK

-Create a search engine to find the workers in the list, either the old ones or the new ones: Thi is NOT OK.

The employees data base is a JSON file included in the .src folder.

I am doubtful about how to create the filter and how the function should be if the same must be in the App.js or maybe another component.

Link to github repository:
https://github.com/guslopezr/desafio_renderizacion_listaempleados

App published on Vercel (Search function not yet working).
https://desafio-renderizacion-listaempleados.vercel.app/

Any help will be much apprecciated.

Best,
Gustavo

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **useCallback** hook at **buscarEmpleado** method and add **datosTabla** state as follow:

```
function App() {
  const [empleados, setEmpleados] = useState(trabajadoresDB);
  const [empleado, setEmpleado] = useState({});
  const [datosTabla, setDatosTabla] = useState(trabajadoresDB);
  //console.log(empleados);

  // to update datosTabla on any empleados changes
  useEffect(() => {
    setDatosTabla(empleados);
  }, [empleados]);

  const guardarEmpleado = (empleado) => {
    setEmpleados([...empleados, empleado]);
  };

  const buscarEmpleado = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const search = empleados.filter((empleado) =>
        empleado.name.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
      );
      console.log(search);
      setDatosTabla(search);
    },
    [empleados]
  );

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header class />
      <Buscador buscarEmpleado={buscarEmpleado} />

      <br />

      <FormularioApp guardarEmpleado={guardarEmpleado} />

      <TablaEmpleados key={empleado.id} empleados={datosTabla} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This is amazing, thanks a lot for your support. I will give this a try at the earliest.